# phpMyAdmin - Double clicking to view Serialized Array breaks the code

Tags: mysql, serialization, phpmyadmin

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that uses serialized arrays to store data entered through the Dashboard. The plugin is Genesis Extender.  Here's what happened:

> I viewed the data in phpMyAdmin.
>   I double clicked on the field.
>   I copied/pasted it elsewhere.
>   I didn't change anything.
>   When I clicked off of the field, the program returned, "1 row updated"

Now, I can't see the data via the Dashboard.  I have a very limited understanding of how serialized arrays work.  I don't understand why I can't view the data that is sitting in the database via the Dashboard any longer.  Please help!

Comment: I was told that the problem is taking this action in phpMyAdmin will convert characters w/o knowing it - changing the length of the fields.

Comment: I think your comment is the only possible answer to why the row was updated. Instead of clicking off the field, pressing escape should cancel whatever you did/didn't do. I also prefer MySQL Workbench over phpMyAdmin

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Also, what datatype is the column? I believe current best-practices are to use a BLOB data, which displays in my system as `[BLOB - 150 B]` (and still isn't editable by double-clicking even with `Show BLOB contents` selected)